# Blowfish authentication in cakephp 2.4.2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4, blowfish

Can anybody help me with cakephp 2.4.2 auth using blowfish, I'm new to cakephp auth so I've googled it up but didn't find any solution for my problem.

Here is my code

For App Controller

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'RequestHandler',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

For Model

```
        public function beforeSave($options = array()){
        if (isset($this->data[$this->name]['password'])) {
            $this->data[$this->name]['password'] = Security::hash($this->data[$this->alias]['password'], 'blowfish');
        }
        return true;
    }
```

For Controller

```
                if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'dashboard', 'builder' => true));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->write('flash', array('You Have entered wrong username or password.', 'failure'));
                    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'builder' => true));
                }
```

Comment: Not able to authenticate user.

Comment: `Security::hash` is deprecated, use the password hasher classes instead as documented if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your AppController:

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        AuthComponent::ALL => array(
            'userModel' => 'User',
            'fields' => array(
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password'
            ),
            'scope' => $user_scope,
        ), 'Form'=> array(
                'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
            )
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

For blowfish you need to provide a salt, that is a `bcrypt` salt

from docs
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html#Security::hash

```
// Create a hash using bcrypt
Security::setHash('blowfish');
$salt = Security::hash(Configure::read('Security.salt'));

// $salt is a previously generated bcrypt salt.
$passwordHash = Security::hash($password, 'blowfish', $salt);
```

I would recommend using separate salt for each user/password, in that case instead of using security salt for creating the bcrypt salt, use some random string, and then save the salt in your database along with password hash.

during user login use this scenario

- 1) fetch the salt and the password hash from database
- 2) using salt and the plain text password provided by user during login to generate the password hash
- 3) compare newly generated password hash with what was fetched from the db.
- 4) if they match login the user, otherwise show error

for login use `if ($this->Auth->login($userData)) {` and `$userData` should be array like

```
array ('username' => 'the_username', 'password' => 'the_password');
```

---

**authentication:**

```
$userData = $this->User->findByEmail('myEmail@gmail.com', array('username', 'password', 'salt'));

$passwordHash = Security::hash($userPlainTextPassword, 'blowfish', $userData['User']['salt']);

if ($passwordHash == $userData['User']['password']) {
  if (  $this->Auth->login($userData['User'])) {
     // ok
  } else {
    // smth wrong
  }
} else {
  // wrong username or password
}
```

btw, for comparing the hashes you better use standard time comparison, read more here

https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#properhashing

Comment: Thanx for the rply, just giving it a try

Comment: I'm able to make the hash right, but the problem is in user authentication.

Comment: did u do the listed steps, can u confirm that the password hash that is in db is equal to the hash that was returned hashing the provided plain text password ? if so, and you feed `array ('username' => 'the_username', 'password' => 'the_password');` array to `$this->Auth->login` function it should be fine, pls check again maybe ur missing smth ? if does not work, please edit ur answer and post your code login part, so I can show further assistance

Comment: Can you please tell me how to check the hashed password value at authentication